# How to attach an angular animation to the transition between steps in the angular horizontal stepper cdk?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-material-stepper

I'm using the `cdk` stepper for building a new stepper but I can't find a way to attach an angular animation for the transition between steps. Can somebody help me?

I've tried [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animations-lib-horizontal-step-transition-animation) solution by replacing the variable `current` by the `stepper.selectedIndex` but it's not working as expected.

```
<app-custom-stepper #stepper>
   <cdk-step [@stepTransition]="stepper.selectedIndex === 0 ? 'current' : 'previous'
      ">
     <p>This is any content of "Step 1"</p>
   </cdk-step>
   <cdk-step  [@stepTransition]="stepper.selectedIndex === 1 ? 'current'
          : stepper.selectedIndex > 1
          ? 'previous'
          : 'next'
      ">
     <p>This is any content of "Step 2"</p>
   </cdk-step>
</app-custom-stepper>
```